# Проблема с парсингом на PHP

Tags: php, curl

Надо написать парсер на php. С яндексом работает нормально, но youtube.com, например, не парсит.

Код:

```
include 'curl_query.php';
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = curl_get($url1);
$dom = str_get_html($html);    

$cocos = $dom->find('#header');

foreach ($cocos as $coc) {
    echo $coc->plaintext;
}
```

Код curl_query.php:

```
function curl_get($url, $referer = 'https://www.google.ru') {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        return $data;
    }
```

Ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\parser\parcer.php:39 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\parser\parcer.php on line 39

Comment: Ну и от нас вы что хотите?

Comment: Чтобы с ютубом работало.

Comment: Покажите, что у вас в `simple_html_dom.php`

Comment: @YuriyProkopets это библиотека для парсинга сайтов

Comment: @Даниил, так вот ваша библиотека вместо объекта `$dom` возвращает `false`, скорее это связано с тем, что `curl` не возвращает контент страницы

Comment: Некоторые сайты так просто не спарсишь. Например, тот же ВК. Они сильно заморачиваются с защитой